# Building a Minimum heap

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a min heap using the library function make_heap .Please point out the error in the class compare. The root element should have been the minimum element in the array but it is not.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
class compare {
        bool operator()(pair<int, int> lhs,pair<int, int> rhs) const 
        {
            return lhs.second < rhs.second;
        }
    };
int main()
{
    int arr[]={9,2,5,7,3,5,7,5,4,5,6,4,5};
    make_heap(arr,arr+13,compare);
    cout<<arr[0];
}
```

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? What does it do, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: *"It's not working"* is not a problem description. Other than concluding that it's probably just too lazy to work you're not going to get anything more substantial.

Comment: I want to build a min heap using lib fn max_heap ...Plz suggest some way. I need it urgently. Plz i m a noob.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
bool cmp(int l, int r) const
    {
        return l< r;
    }
```

i.e. not in a class (if you wish make it static

Then

```
make_heap(arr,arr+13,cmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a `pair` in your comparator ?

Use :

```
class compare {
public: //Make it public 
        bool operator()(const int &lhs, const int& rhs)  const
        {
            return lhs < rhs;
        }

    };
```

And then

```
int arr[]={9,2,5,7,3,5,7,5,4,5,6,4,5};
make_heap(arr,arr+13,compare()); //Notice ()
for(auto i:arr)
  cout<<i<<" ";
```

See [HERE](http://ideone.com/5nASZX)

Comment: Do not need to pass ints as references - that is overkill.

Comment: @EdHeal overkill in what sense ?
I'm just sticking to `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);` from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap)

Comment: Can u plz explain how do we use a comparator, I dint get what u did here,

Comment: @P0W - In the sense that under the bonnet (hood for the yanks) references are implemented as pointers. Therefore just using the plain integer is cheaper.

Comment: @Ed Can you point me to the section in the C++ standards that mandates how a compiler must implement references?

Comment: @Anshul A class with a overloaded `()` operator ,taking two `int`s for comparison. This is used with `std::make_heap`. Ref. [functor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/1870232) for details

Comment: - How else would you implement them?

Comment: @POW thnx u vei mch dude

Comment: @Ed Not that I'm an authority on the topic, but my optimizer would probably consider passing an object by value when implementing a const reference. A `const int&` may likely wind up by value in a register, unless the C++ standard explicitly mandates how to implement references. Seeing that Microsoft's compiler generates identical code for `const int&` and `int` parameters I don't see the *"overkill"* you were talking about.

Comment: @llnspectable - Why rely on the compiler making assumptions when you can thwart it and be explicit

Comment: @Ed I'm not relying on a compiler to make assumptions. I'm just open to the idea that optimizers are pretty damn smart these days. If you can follow a consistent scheme (as P0W did and explained) then by all means, do! If your team has coding conventions that mandate a different scheme then that's fine as well. Promoting dogmatic rules based on made up facts, on the other hand, is questionable.

Comment: @llnspectable - Why are you depending on the compiler being smart enough? Does that mean that a programmer is not clever enough to realise that not using references in this instance is a better option?

Comment: @Ed I rely on a compiler being smart mostly because I don't have any evidence otherwise. I also do trust developers to be clever, hell, even I am! In a project of any size, however, I do value those developers who are consistent instead of clever. And I guess I simply don't see why passing a value is a better option, other than a compiler being free to generate worse code when passing a const reference. With compilers usually competing in generating good code this doesn't seem to be an issue. All of this is besides the point: If you provide a rationale make sure it's not made up.

Comment: @EdHeal You have the idea of a reference being a pointer, but that's only necessary for a non-const reference, a const reference is better thought of as an `alias` for an object.